# Bin and count data to normalize Y axis

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, geopandas

I have this area and diameter data:

```
    DIAMETER    AREA
0   3.039085    1230000
1   2.763617    1230000
2   2.052176    1230000
3   9.498093    1230000
4   2.680360    1230000
```

I want to bin the data by 1 (2-3,3-4 etc.) and count the number of diameters that are in those bins so that it's organized something like this:

```
2-3  3-4  4-5  5-6  6-7  7-8  8-9  9-10
3     1    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

My end goal is to then grab these counts and divide them by the area in order to normalize the counts.
Lastly I will plot the normalized counts (y) by the bins (x).

I tried to use a method using pd.cut but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

To do this you are wanting a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram). This can easily be achieved with the [`hist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html) method of your pandas `DataFrame` (this itself, just uses the [`hist`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) plot method from Matplotlib, which uses NumPy's [`histogram`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) function), for example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# create a version of the data for the example
data = pd.DataFrame({"DIAMETER": [3.039085, 2.763617, 2.052176, 9.498093, 2.680360]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()  # create a figure to plot onto

bins = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]  # set the histogram bin edges
data.hist(
    column="DIAMETER",  # the column to histogram
    bins=bins,  # set the bin edges
    density=True,   # this normalises the histogram  
    ax=ax,  # the Matplotlib axis onto which to plot
)

fig.show()  # show the plot
```

This gives:

[image]

where the Pandas `hist` function will automatically add a plot title based on the column name.

If you don't specify the `bins` keyword, then it will automatically generate 10 bins bounded by the range of your data, but these will not necessarily be integer spaced. If you wanted to ensure integer spaced bins for arbitrary data, then you could set the bins with:

```py
import numpy as np

bins = np.arange(
    np.floor(data["DIAMETER"].min()),
    np.ceil(data["DIAMETER"].max()) + 1,
)
```

If you want a plot like suggested in your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75330583/how-can-i-do-math-to-data-binned-and-counted-in-pandas), then purely with NumPy and Matplotlib you could do:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# set bins
bins = np.arange(
    np.floor(data["DIAMETER"].min()) - 1,  # subtract 1, so we have a zero count bin at the start
    np.ceil(data["DIAMETER"].max()) + 2,  # add 2, so we have a zero count bin at the end
)

# generate histogram
counts, _ = np.histogram(
    data["DIAMETER"],
    bins=bins,
    density=True,  # normalise histogram
)

dx_2 = 0.5 * (bins[1] - bins[0])  # bin half spacing (we know this is 1/2, but lets calculate it in case you change it!)

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(
    bins[:-1] + dx_2,
    counts,
    marker="s",  # square marker like the plot from your other question
)

ax.set_xlabel("Diameter")
ax.set_ylabel("Probability density")

fig.show()
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: this is really helpful. How is the histogram being normalized? I assume that It's summing and then dividing by the total. Is there a way that I can normalize the data by dividing the counts by the area?

Comment: The `denisty` argument does normalise by the area under the histogram, it just happens that in this case, with bins widths of 1, that normalisation is just the same as the sum of the of values in all bins. If you change the bins widths, it will still correctly normalise.

Comment: If you want to see how it actually calculates this, it it just here https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.24.0/numpy/lib/histograms.py#L882.